# How to add random map location function to my google maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have my API to where I can type in a city and state and it will take my marker to that location. How would I use `Math.random` to create a button that would take me to a random location?

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var coords = {
    lat: parseFloat(/*[[${location.lat}]]*/) || 39.9612,
    lng: parseFloat(/*[[${location.lng}]]*/) || -82.9988
};
var city = /*[[${location.city}]]*/;
var state = /*[[${location.state}]]*/;

    /*]]>*/

function randomBetween() {
    var random = new google.maps.LatLng( (Math.random()*(85*2)-85), (Math.random()*(180*2)-180) );
}
</script>

    <input type="button" onclick="randomBetween()" value="Click" />
```

When I run the function `randomBetween`, i want it to take me to a random location. My button doesn't do anything as of right now.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples of how to create markers at random locations within the map bounds in several examples in the documentation, one is:

- [Using Closures in Event Listeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure)

```
var lngSpan = bounds.east - bounds.west;
var latSpan = bounds.north - bounds.south;
for (var i = 0; i < secretMessages.length; ++i) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: bounds.south + latSpan * Math.random(),
      lng: bounds.west + lngSpan * Math.random()
    },
    map: map
  });
}
```

To add a marker at your "random" location and center the map there:

```
function randomBetween() {
  var random = new google.maps.LatLng( (Math.random()*(85*2)-85), (Math.random()*(180*2)-180) );
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: random
  });
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lrfe5htk/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    randomBetween();
  })
}

function randomBetween() {
  var random = new google.maps.LatLng((Math.random() * (85 * 2) - 85), (Math.random() * (180 * 2) - 180));
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: random
  });
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 95%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" value="random location" type="button" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```